# what should i do to avoid moving element on web page(html,css,jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning jQuery, and I wrote something like this:

```
$('#bt1').on('click',function() {
    $('#area1').fadeToggle(1000);
});
```

and it works fine for one element. When I add one more element and place it next to the first element, the second element takes the place of the first when i click on `bt1`, because the first element disappears.

My question is: *how to keep elements (`div`) in place, where they are at the beginning, when one element is hidden?*

Comment: Can you please paste your HTML as well here

Comment: Make your elements *invisible* instead of *hidden*.

Comment: Not sure about this from the code sample you have provided. But assuming `area1` is the ID of the DIV, ID is unique. No two elements can have the same ID.

Comment: @meskobalazs I think in jquery invisible and hidden both are same

Comment: In jQuery yes, I am talking about CSS.

Comment: Assuming you don't have duplicate ID's, and that you just want the element to take up space, use [`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) instead

Comment: Use below given solution in fadeToggle it's applying display:none but in below solution I have updated it

Comment: I have buttons and area with diffrent id's. I saw solution that i wrote in tutorial and there everything was fine. My problem is when I click bt1, first area fade but second take place of first and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below solution instead of fadeToggle

```js
$('#bt1').on('click',function() {
   $("#area1").animate({opacity:($("#area1").css('opacity')==1)?0:1});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="area1">AREA 1
  </div>

<div id="area2">AREA 2
  </div>

<input type="button" value="submit" id="bt1">
```

Comment: sure it is a good solution, but i just started to learn and i saw in tutorial solution with fadeToggle and it works but i don't have a whole code only piece with jQuery

Comment: I look for solution with fadeToggle, but i don't know where I make mistake that did't work well, I mean that when I click button1 the area1 fade, but the second are take place of the first area and so on

Comment: Yes, it will wlays happen in case of FadeToggle because fadetoggle is doing display:none to content that's why second content is taking place of first one

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to toggle visibility and keep the element in the DOM because fading out completely removes the element leaving a gap in the page

Answer (score 0):

```
instead of .fadeIn() you can .animate({opacity:1})
and instead of .fadeOut() you can .animate({opacity:0})
```

and then, if you want to disable click events on hidden control, call this method

```
$('#YourElementId').css({visibility: "hidden"});
```